# Loading Images into Div Dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, html, dynamic

I have a list of profile images which appear in a "menu drop down" div which is initially hidden via CSS. I would like to load these images dynamically (as a list) when each menu item is selected, so as to reduce the page loading time. How is this possible?

Comment: Hopefully, you mean you would like to cache these images. If you start loading them while they are being selected, there's a good chance that they will take a long time to load.

Comment: you can use jquery Lazy loading http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: Have you considered loading the whole content with AJAX? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Answer (score 3):

Try to use:

```
$("#divID").html("<img  style='position:absolute' src='path/to/the/ajax_loader.gif'>");
```

If you using ajax:

```
    function sendAjax()
    {
        $("#divID").html("<img  style='position:absolute' src='path/to/the/ajax_loader.gif'>");

         // you ajax code

        $("#divID").html(ajaxResponse);
    }
```

you can also use `document.getElementById('divID').innerHTML` instead of `$("#divID").html()`. its also work fine

If you use this method, doesn't need to hide the div using css. its automatically remove after the ajax response.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can try this:

```
<div id="desiredDiv">
</div>
<script>
var images = [
    'http://www.example.com/img/image1.png',
    'http://www.example.com/img/image2.png',
    'http://www.example.com/img/image3.png',
    ...
];
for(var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
    $('#desiredDiv').append('<img src="'+images[i]+'" alt="" />');
}
</script>
```

Comment: i hope it serves your prob upto some extent , if not let me know

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML leave out the src attribute on each image tag. Instead, add an attribute called data-src and give it the image url.

Then, when the menu is displayed, run the following script:

```
$('.menu-class img').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('src'));
});
```

Said script requires jquery if you don't already have it

Comment: Although, as Alex W pointed out, you may want to do this in the document ready event instead of when the menu opens so the image is ready BEFORE the menu opens - not after.

Comment: It might be better to use: `$(this).data('src')`

Comment: Edited per Code Pirate's comment. Cool, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the list of images in a JavaScript variable:

```
var images = [
    'http://www.example.com/img/image1.png',
    'http://www.example.com/img/image2.png',
    'http://www.example.com/img/image3.png',
    ...
];
```

Then you can load the image whenever you need by creating the image tag:

```
var i = 0; // the index of the image in the list
var $img = $( '<img>' ).attr({'src':images[i]});
```

Just append the image to your div and it will be loaded automatically by the browser.